# SQL percentile function and joining 2 queries:

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to retrieve the max, min and the 90th percentile from a table of results.
I want the 90th percentile for duration based on the timestamp_ in asc order.

My Table looks like this:

```
TIMESTAMP_                DURATION
24/01/2000 12:04:45.120     454
26/10/200  12:13:49.440     301
06/01/2001 15:12:05.760     245
23/01/2001 10:56:55.680     462
16/02/2001 12:10:39.360     376
19/04/2001 09:22:45.120     53
13/05/2001 12:36:34.560     330
30/05/2001 14:47:45.600     796
07/08/2001 08:51:47.520     471
25/08/2001 14:24:08.640     821
```

I have 2 queries to retrive this info, but is there a simpler solution by using one query. here are my queries:

```
 Select MIN(DURATION), MAX(DURATION)
 From t 
  ;


  Select DURATION as nthPercentile from t
  Where TIMESTAMP_ =
    (
    Select
    Percentile_disc(0.90) within group (order by TIMESTAMP_) AS nth
    From t
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: Tag updated with Oracle. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytics:

```
SQL> SELECT duration, max_duration, min_duration
  2    FROM (SELECT duration, ts,
  3                 Percentile_disc(0.90) within GROUP(ORDER BY ts) OVER() nth,
  4                 MAX(duration) OVER() max_duration,
  5                 MIN(duration) OVER() min_duration
  6             FROM t)
  7   WHERE ts = nth;

  DURATION MAX_DURATION MIN_DURATION
---------- ------------ ------------
       471          821           53
```

However, I'm not really sure that this is the result you want. Why would you want to order by timestamp? The resulting duration is the duration of the 90th percentile row **based on timestamp**, not duration.

A more straightforward and logical result may be what you need:

```
SQL> SELECT Percentile_disc(0.90) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY duration) nth,
  2         MAX(duration) max_duration,
  3         MIN(duration) min_duration
  4    FROM t;

       NTH MAX_DURATION MIN_DURATION
---------- ------------ ------------
       796          821           53
```

Comment: The straightforward query gave me the 90th percentile of duration, but the query above did the trick. Thank you

Comment: sorry is there a way to get the 90th and the 95th within one query?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

```
Select MAX(case when TIMESTAMP_ = nth then DURATION end) as nthPercentile,
       MAX(MAXDUR) as MAXDUR, MAX(MINDUR) as MINDUR
from (Select DURATION, TIMESTAMP_, MIN(DURATION) as MINDUR, MAX(DURATION) as MAXDUR
             Percentile_disc(0.90) within group (order by TIMESTAMP_) AS nth
      from t
     ) tsum join
     t
     on t.TIMESTAMP_ = tsum.TIMESTAMP_;
```

Comment: I get a ORA-00937: not a single-group group function error with this query

Comment: @user3715596 . . . Yes.  The duration limits should be calculated in the subquery.  The key idea is moving the percentile calculation to the `from` clause from the `where` clause.